# Mutt not being configured to use gmail

Tags: mutt

After reading lot of pages I tried below lines in .muttrc

```
set smtp_url="smtp://xxxxx@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass="XXXXXXXX"
set from="xxxxxx@gmail.com"
set realname="xxxxx"
```

but when initializing mutt following error is given

```
Error in /root/.muttrc, line 1: mtp_url=smtp://xxxxx@smtp.gmail.com:587/: unknown command
Error in /root/.muttrc, line 2: smtp_pass: unknown variable
```

mutt -v output is given below

```
Mutt 1.4.2.2i (2006-07-14)
Copyright (C) 1996-2002 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 2.6.32-200.13.1.el5uek (x86_64) [using ncurses 5.5]
Compile options:
-DOMAIN
-DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  -USE_SETGID  -USE_DOTLOCK  -DL_STANDALONE
+USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_GSS  +USE_SSL  +USE_SASL
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM
+HAVE_PGP  -BUFFY_SIZE -EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_GETSID  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO
-ISPELL
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/usr/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
-MIXMASTER
To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
To report a bug, please use the flea(1) utility.
```

I just need to send mail using google smtp server. Is there any other simple client available which can be used in bash script to send mail with attachments.

Thanks.